# Generate random colors for leaflet map

Tags: r, leaflet, shiny

Great R Gurus,

I am struggling to find a way to randomly mix discrete colors for my leaflet map for a large number of observations. 
The problem is the following command put similar colors next to each other which makes it hard to distinguish on the map.

```
library(leaflet) 
previewColors(colorFactor("RdYlBu", domain = NULL), LETTERS[1:26])
```

[image]

Is there any way to mix colors in a way it becomes A,Z,B,Y and so on...

Your time to answer is highly appreciated...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
library(leaflet) 
set.seed(50)
previewColors(colorFactor(sample(colors(),26), domain = NULL), LETTERS[1:26])
```

To get an output as follows:[image]

Or you could do something like this:
    library(leaflet) 
    set.seed(500)
    previewColors(colorFactor(sample(rainbow(26),26), domain = NULL), LETTERS[1:26])

To get the output as follows:
[image]